# Type parameter on method is same as its outer type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, generic-programming

I have an interface like this:

```
public interface IStuff
{
    bool DoSomethingWith<T>(T type);
}
```

And this class that implements it

```
    public class MyStuff<T> : IStuff
    {

        readonly ISomeClass<T> _cls;

        public MyStuff(ISystemCache cache)
        {
            _cls= cache.Get<T>();
        }

        public bool DoSomethingWith<T>(T type)
        {
            //dummy code here that returns a bool
            Type theType = typeof(T);
            return theType == typeof(T);
        }
     }
```

Now the reason the type `T` is on the Class MyStuff is because I want it to be available in the constructor of the class that implements IStuff. MyStuff will be passed in some type to work with in its DoSomethingWith method.

Now DoSomethingWith also has a type `T` because I want it to be available on all the classes that implement IStuff.

`IStuff` will be having at most one or two implementations; at the moment just one, but once I finalize the design there will be another one added. But there will about 5-6 different implementations of `ISomeClass` sent in to the `MyStuff` class. I don't want to repeat `MyStuff` for each implementation of `ISomeClass`.  Later on `MyStuff_V2` will do something else will the implementations of `ISomeClass` that will be sent in.

How do I go about designing this so that I don't get that compiler warning "The Type parameter T has the same name as the Type parameter from the outer class `MyStuff<T>` ?

**EDIT**
This is a very contrived example that may not be perfect, but the objective is to be able to create a generic type on the interface methods that is also available to the constructor of the classes that implement that interface.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to make `IStuff` generic:

```
public interface IStuff<T>
{
    bool DoSomethingWith(T type);
}
```

change `MyStuff<T>` to implement `IStuff<T>`:

```
public class MyStuff<T> : IStuff<T>
```

and with that you can just remove generic parameter from `DoSomething` implementation:

```
public bool DoSomethingWith(T type)
{
    //dummy code here that returns a bool
    Type theType = typeof(T);
    return theType == typeof(T);
}
```

Comment: IStuff will be having at most one or two implementations; at the moment just one, but once I finalize the design there will be another one added. But there will about 5-6 different implementations of ISomeClass sent in to the MyStuff class. I don't want to repeat MyStuff for each implementation of ISomeClass. With MyStuff<T> : IStuff<T> that is what will happen right? Later on MyStuff_V2 will do something else will the implementations of ISomeClass that will be sent in

Comment: @user20358 - So the end goal is to have just one `MyStuff` class without the generic `T` parameter?  Otherwise you will end up with multiples anyways (ex: `MyStuff<ISomeObj>` and `MyStuff<IAnother>`, etc)

Comment: At the moment lets just say one implementation, so just MyStuff, but yes it will need to take in MyStuff<ISomeObj> along with MyStuff<IAnother>. If it were just one type I could have limited it with the where clause. But thats not the case and I need to have it work with multiple types which are unforseen at the moment. Inside MyStuff I will be using third party frameworks that can work with any type passed to them. My guess is they use reflection for that. The job of MyStuff is to just pass N number of types in to those third party frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the two types to be different?  Just change the type:

```
public bool DoSomethingWith<T2>(T2 type)
{
   //dummy code here that returns a bool
   Type theType = typeof(T2);
   return theType == typeof(T);
}
```

Otherwise you'll have to do what @Marcin suggests.

A more complete example:

```
void Main()
{
   IStuff s = new MyStuff<int>();
   Console.WriteLine(s.DoSomethingWith(2.34)); // compare will be false (double != int)
   Console.WriteLine(s.DoSomethingWith(5)); // compare will be true (int == int)
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public interface IStuff
{
    bool DoSomethingWith<T2>(T2 type);
}

public class MyStuff<T> : IStuff
{
   public MyStuff()
   {
      // Do whatever with type T
   }

   public bool DoSomethingWith<T2>(T2 type)
   {
      // dummy code here that returns a bool
      Type theType = typeof(T2);
      return theType == typeof(T);
   }
}
```

Comment: They will be the same. The methods of MyStuff will be operating on the same type sent in via the constructor